# Is there a way to set Global Variables to be available by default within PHP functions?

Tags: php, function, scope, default, global

Is there any way to do this / specify this in the `php.ini` configuration file? It would be really nice, at least for local server purposes, just to write functions without having to write the global keyword every time a global variable is used within the method.

Any way to do this?

EDIT:

What I mean is being to simply write this:

- Example file "**index.php**":

  > $MY_ARRAY = array();
  >
  > include("functions.php");
- And then in "**functions.php**":

  > function addToArray($pMessage) {
  >
  > $MY_ARRAY[] = "<a href='somelink.php'>$pMessage</a>";
  >
  > }

Instead of:

- And then in "**functions.php**":

  > function addToArray($pMessage) {
  >
  > global $MY_ARRAY;
  >
  > $MY_ARRAY[] = "<a href='somelink.php'>$pMessage</a>";
  >
  > }

Comment: I think a more common practice is to set environment variables and access them via the `$_ENV` super-global.

Comment: So $_ENV does not have to be imported with "global $_ENV;" at the beginning of each functions?

Comment: Well for the time being, just the one array, but that may grow later to a dozen or more,  possibly.

Comment: consider changing approach to your problem, ie. using a class

Comment: You can use the $GLOBALS variable. For example `$GLOBALS['MY_ARRAY']`

Comment: DON'T DO THIS!!! And don't keep using the `global` keyword... learn to pass arguments to functions. If PHP was intended to work this way, they'd never have disabled it in the first place.

Comment: @MarkBaker - I realize this may be bad practice, but if the method only ever modifies one array (no matter what...) then it's a bit redundant to pass the Array every time. That would result writing longer function arguments list everytime I want to invoke it.

Comment: Your comment about `just one array, but that may grow later to a dozen or more` rather contradicts that. There's no "may be" about it being bad practise.... it __is__ bad practise. Learn to code well, and it will stand you in good stead in the future; learn to use bad practises knowing that they are bad, and you will never become a good code.

Comment: @amigura what about it? Not sure I understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! You can setup a prepend file in PHP.
See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: What does this have to do with omitting "global $varame" in function definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand the purpose. But if I need to just remove the `GLOBAL` keyword from mentioning everytime, I would prefer to use a class with static array.

Something like this:

```
<?php

//  Config.php
class Config {
    public static $MY_ARRAY = array();
}

?>
```

And then include this file from your loader just call like this:

```
function addToArray($pMessage) {

    Config::$MY_ARRAY[] = "<a href='somelink.php'>$pMessage</a>";

}
```

That will work.